# getting Error: [$injector:modulerr] using angularjs datatable?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I am creating one small demo for getting user list and also login using angularjs with web api.and I am using datatable for showing user  list.then I am include datatable in module file then first time run the project getting like this error.and then remove 'datatable' from the module working very well.so i can not understand where is my mistke.

this is my app.js code:

```
var app = angular.module("Demo", ['ngRoute','datatables']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.

        when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'home/dashboard',
            controller: 'dashboardcontroller'
        }).           

        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home/login'
        });}]);
```

this is my included datatable module. i am remove here datatable it's working fine but again add datatable getting error from the module.

this is my script ordering :

```
 <script src="~/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/angular-datatables.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/services.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/controller.js"></script>
```

this is error is getting:

[image]

so this is my code any one know where is mistake then please let me know.

Comment: Why have you included angularjs files twice? `angular.min.js` and `angular.js`? remove the any one of them.

Comment: @Pradeepb which one need to remove any idea? i am remove angular.js but still issue is getting.

Comment: you can replace the  `angular.min.js` with `js/angular.js` and delete second import. I am suggesting this because for development minified versions wont be useful for debugging.

Comment: sorry but i have try this wave but still issue is getting i don't know where is wrong.any idea then please let me know.

Comment: whats the error your are getting please post the error

Comment: please look at the answer provided by @deividfortuna.

Comment: try removing jqury data tabale

Comment: no guys still issue is getting.any one know other wave

Comment: instead of posting image give the  error raw :) it is of no use the image that is

Comment: i am remove 'datatable' from module then code working very well but then i add still issue is getting.

Comment: hii thanks for that give many suggestion but now issue is gone

Comment: thank you so much guys for that give me many suggestion @Boss,@Pradeepb,@Gaurav,@deividfortuna

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the duplicated import of angular and add the jQuery before the angular's files. Like this:

```
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/angular-datatables.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/services.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/controller.js"></script>
```

The angular-datatables provides a `datatables` directive you can add to your `<table>`

Like this `<table datatable="">...</table>`

You can have more information here: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/gettingStarted

Comment: still issue is getting.

Comment: are you using the directive? something like `<table datatable=""></table>`

Comment: no i am not used directive.just simple used datatable for the show list of user.

Comment: I just saw your console error, you need to remove the duplicated dependency of angular

Comment: means which type of duplicated dependency of angular remove?

Comment: in your original question you are importing to angular files `<script src="~/assets/angular.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="~/assets/js/angular.js"></script>` please remove `<script src="~/assets/angular.min.js"></script>`

Also the documentation provide the follow information:
The angular-datatables provides a `datatables` directive you can add to your `<table>`

Comment: still issue is getting i don't know why this type error is getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137660/discussion-between-deividfortuna-and-hiren).

Answer (score 0):

You need angular-datatable plugin also for inject datatable service in controller

see [angular-datatable](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/angular-datatables.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/services.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/controller.js"></script>
```

Try with this

Comment: @Hiren try this solution

Comment: sorry but still getting same issue in console.

Comment: which version of angular are you using ? and please post the error link that you are getting

Comment: AngularJS v1.3.3 is used.

Comment: do the file exist in that location ?

Comment: did you remove the jquery data table ?

Comment: hii thanks for that give many suggestion but now issue is gone

Comment: actually i am not include all js on login page and this my all js is on layout page so that's getting error.sorry guys i have more waste of time